# Simple tree display of WordPress menu

Tags: php, plugins

I want to display my wordpress menu in the form of a simple tree like this:

```
  >First menu item
     >sub-menu-1
        >sub-sub-menu-1
     >sub-menu-2
     >sub-menu-3

  >Second menu item
     >sub-menu-1

  >Third menu item
     >sub-menu-1
     >sub-menu-2
     >sub-menu-3
```

I know there is this [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) but how do I add class to sub-menu so that I can give some left margin and make it look like, it's nested?

Comment: It is likely that Wordpress does not support that out of the box for you (if you don't want to set each items class manually in the menu editor). One way to add the functionality you're looking for is to provide your own *walker*, see the docs about `$walker` on the codex page you've linked.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below css in your style,

```
ul ul {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: No, that's not what i mean, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu this function returns all menu items as a single list(no nested ul li 's even if my menu has nested items)

Comment: Can you demonstrate by what you mean by single list ?

Comment: It returns something like this, <ul><li>First menu item</li><li>sub-menu-1</li><li>sub-sub-menu-1</li>...</ul> instead of <ul><li>First menu item</li><ul><li>sub-menu-1</li></ul><ul><li>sub-sub-menu-1</li></ul>...</ul>

Comment: @Rao - It should not , How exactly you using wp_nav_menu function can you post that too ?

Comment: yes it doesn't, my bad, there was no sub-menu in my custom menu, so it was displaying one ul and all li 's.

Comment: @Rao - So solved now ?

Comment: yes, but its not displaying the way I want it, <?php
$defaults = array(
 'theme_location'  => '',
 'menu'            => 'Regular Categories',
 'container'       => 'div',
 'container_class' => '',
 'container_id'    => '',
 'menu_class'      => 'menu',
 'menu_id'         => '',
 'echo'            => true,
 'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
 'before'          => '',
 'after'           => '',
 'link_before'     => '',
 'link_after'      => '',
 'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
 'depth'           => 3,
 'walker'          => ''
);
wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30546/discussion-between-rao-and-rikesh)